# I2PD with Ejabberd XMPP Server: how to?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

Is there a way to use I2PD with Ejabberd XMPP Server?
I haven't found any specific modules.

Looking forward to your kind help

Comment: But what is I2PD?

Comment: @Badlop https://i2pd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I am not aware of anything like this for ejabberd. Alternative, https://chefkochblog.wordpress.com/2018/06/02/how-to-use-xmpp-i2p-to-build-your-own-decentralized-messenger/